# Somar total de um loop

Tags: php, loop

estou tentando fazer uma soma total de um "for" mas ta tudo muito louco ou "zerado"...

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

        $total_receitas_recebidas = 0;
        $total_receitas_a_receber = 0;
        $total_despesas_pagas = 0;
        $total_despesas_a_pagar = 0;

        $sinalNegativo = "";

        if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="receita")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="S")){
            $cor=' style="color:green;"'; 
            $situacao="Receita recebida";
            $total_receitas_recebidas = $total_receitas_recebidas + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
        }

        if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="receita")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="N")){
            $cor=' style="color:blue;"';
            $situacao="Receita à receber";
            $total_receitas_a_receber = $total_receitas_a_receber + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
        }

        if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="despesa")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="S")){
            $cor=' style="color:orange;"';
            $situacao="Despesa paga";
            $sinalNegativo = "-";
            $total_despesas_pagas = $total_despesas_pagas + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
        }

        if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="despesa")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="N")){
            $cor=' style="color:red;"';
            $situacao="Despesa à pagar";
            $sinalNegativo = "-";
            $total_despesas_a_pagar = $total_despesas_a_pagar + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
        }

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>';echo $data[$i]["info_para_cliente"];  echo '</td>';
        echo '<td>';echo converteDataParaMostrar($data[$i]['data_vencimento']);  
        echo '</td>';
        echo '<td><p'.$cor.'><b>';echo 'R$ '.$sinalNegativo.number_format($data[$i]["valor"], 2, ',', '.'); echo '</b></p></td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }


echo '<input type="hidden" id="total_receitas_recebidas" value="'.number_format($total_receitas_recebidas, 2, ',', '.').'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="total_receitas_a_receber" value="'.number_format($total_receitas_a_receber, 2, ',', '.').'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="total_despesas_pagas" value="'.number_format($total_despesas_pagas, 2, ',', '.').'">';
echo '<input type="hidden" id="total_despesas_a_pagar" value="'.number_format($total_despesas_a_pagar, 2, ',', '.').'">';
```

fiz uns testes com um valor de "150.00" x4 registros mas ele retorna "300.00"????

obs.: isso é um simples fluxo de caixa, a query busca receitas e despesas e cruza tudo.

tenho um modelo igual em outro projeto e funciona perfeito...

Comment: Testou 4x com "150", mas qual o `tipo` e a `situacao`? Onde você recebe o "300"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro você esta instanciando as variáveis de calculo dentro do for ou seja cada loop ele zera o calculo, coloque as variáveis a seguir fora do loop e teste novamente:

```
$total_receitas_recebidas = 0;
$total_receitas_a_receber = 0;
$total_despesas_pagas = 0;
$total_despesas_a_pagar = 0;
```

Comment: era isso mesmo!!! passei vergonha agora kkkkk

Answer (score 2):

Você está zerando os totalizadores em cada passo do laço, além dos totalizadores serem cumulativos, sugiro que seu código fique assim:

```
$total_receitas_recebidas = 0;
$total_receitas_a_receber = 0;
$total_despesas_pagas = 0;
$total_despesas_a_pagar = 0;


for ($i=0; $i < count($data); $i++) {

    if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="receita")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="S")){
        [...]
        $total_receitas_recebidas += $total_receitas_recebidas + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
    }

    if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="receita")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="N")){
       [...]
        $total_receitas_a_receber += $total_receitas_a_receber + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
    }

    if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="despesa")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="S")){
        [...]
        $total_despesas_pagas += $total_despesas_pagas + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
    }

    if(($data[$i]["tipo"]=="despesa")&&($data[$i]["situacao"]=="N")){
        [...]
        $total_despesas_a_pagar += $total_despesas_a_pagar + (float) $data[$i]["valor"];
    }

    echo [...]
}
```

Além disso, me parece que sua váriavel $sinalNegativo não é necessária, uma vez que a função number_format preserva o sinal original do numeral.